# PHPexcel: Image extraction

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have an excel document with multiple records which contains both the text content and images.
I have to save the images according to the record basis. A record has either an image or multiple images or no image. So If I retrieve an image means then I have to name it.

Therefore, I need to find the image's cell name. So that I can easily name it and save it.
But I have no solution to do this. Can we retrieve the cell information using

`$worksheet->getDrawingCollection()`

Please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: read this article it may be helpful for u http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/257231.

Comment: Thanks...Yes, I have read. But there is no tricks to find the corresponding cell information(i.e., G1).

Comment: Vivek-MDU, can you understand that what I'm telling?

Comment: The getCoordinates() method of each drawing object returns the cell

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'll check with getCoordinates().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("MyExcelFile.xls");

foreach ($objPHPExcel->getSheetByName("My Sheet")->getDrawingCollection() as $drawing) {
    if ($drawing instanceof PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing) {
        ob_start();
        call_user_func(
            $drawing->getRenderingFunction(),
            $drawing->getImageResource()
        );
        $imageContents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $cellID = $drawing->getCoordinates();
        //  .... do your save here
    }
}
```