# Processing Picture embedded in uploaded Excel via PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, phpexcel

Objective: 
1)To allow users to embed an image with each ID in an Excelsheet, For Ex: there will be one ID column(1,2,3...n) and one Photo Coloumn. User has to embed one photo to each row in his local system

2) After Step 1, User will upload this excel sheet. In Back-end I will process that uploaded excel sheet via PHPExcel API

3) During process, I will find the ID and the uploaded image object, I will then enter into DB the ID and uploaded image object URL.

Note: In Excel sheet, its the image object, not the URL, So Somehow I have to upload those images also while Excel-sheet uploading

I hope the above is clear.
Please help, how I can try to achieve it. Can PhpWxcel help me, or Do I have to try with something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer, [PHPexcel: Image extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185639/phpexcel-image-extraction) shows how to loop through the images in a worksheet. The getCoordinates() function will return the position of the image, so you can then refer to the cell beside it to get the ID.

With the extracted image, writing it to disk will probably be the easiest way to convert the image data into a usable url.