# How to upload excel sheet image into database in php or in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, excel, laravel, laravel-5

I wonder how to upload excel sheet image into database in php more accurately in laravel.

For example i have an excel sheet which contain product information such as product name, price, product images etc.

Now how do i upload that image to server.
I know how to upload normal text such as product name, product price etc. but not sure how should i upload the image.
I did googling and check here and there but i didn't get any useful information

Can anyone give me some hint or suggestion or solution?
Thank you

Comment: plz see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185639/phpexcel-image-extraction for PHPEXcel

Answer (score 0):

Converting excel into a binary data and you can store those binary data in database.I had tried in mysql using blob data type.

```
$data = base64_encode(file_get_contents('Book2.xlsx'));
$data_result = base64_decode($data);

//to revert back to excel

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename= test.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
echo ($data_result);
```

Comment: I don't see any database code in the code you show.

Comment: Can you leave a comment in the code explaining the part related to "uploading image into a database"?

Comment: The variable "$data_result" contains the excel file binary data.Using insert statement you can push into your database.

Comment: Please neglect the above comment .The variable "$data" contains the excel file binary data.Using insert statement you can push into your database.Example 'insert into table name (column name ) value('".$data."')". I have a doubt whether you want to store the whole excel file contains images into your database or you are trying to store each cell data and cell contains images in the database?